# how to join two Lists in linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have two List A,B which consists integer values ,list A contains 40 to 1 list B contains 40 to 79 i like to both values except 40 and store it in another list using Linq.The resultant list like this {80,80...}. how can i do this? Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to "join" these in a pairwise fashion by index: the first element from each list, then the second element etc. That suggests you want [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx), which was introduced in .NET 4:

```
var zipped = list1.Zip(list2, (x1, x2) => x1 + x2);
```

If you're using .NET 3.5, you can use a separate implementation of the same method, such as the one in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com).

EDIT: Alternatively, Eric Lippert [posted some source code for `Zip`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx) a while ago, too.

Comment: Is it possible to implement in visual studio 2008 express edition

Comment: @ratty: Yes, see my last paragraph. Basically grab the implementation from MoreLINQ.

Comment: skeet sorry for disturb how use that more linq in my visual studio 2008

Comment: @ratty: You could take the source code for Zip.cs (http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Zip.cs?r=171) and just include it in your project or download the whole of MoreLINQ and build it as a class library. Or use Eric Lippert's version.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`IEnumerable<T>.Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344797) method.

Comment: Or in general - `IEnumerable<T>.Join()`.

Comment: I don't *think* he's actually after `Join` here, based on the example in the question. See my answer for my interpretation.

Comment: I had no idea such a method Zip even existed...will have to investigate.

Comment: @Femaref: To be picky, it's `Enumerable.Join()`, which is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Two source arrays.
        var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var array2 = new int[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        // Add elements at each position together.
        var zip = array1.Zip(array2, (a, b) => (a + b));

        // Look at results.
        foreach (var value in zip)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

--- Output of the program ---

7
9
11
13
15

Answer (score 1):

Try Joining them together

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/03/12/joins-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx